# How can I highlight a region on Google Maps in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

When I type name of a region in https://www.google.co.in/maps a polygon is displayed on the website. I want to do the same in my app. Is there any way that could help draw a polygon with the region name provided as done in the website? Please refer the below image to understand what I am trying to ask. Thanks a lot for listening.

[image: Displays a polygon for a given place i.e California in this case.]

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention what I know already and what I have tried. I know that I can draw a Polygon on Google Map by providing co-ordinates (Latitudes, Longitudes) to PolygonOptions. I know how to add a Google Map in an Android App, and I was successfully able to draw a polygon on the map.

**But, what I am trying to ask here is that, is there any way to get the latitudes and longitudes for a region as done in Google Maps Website. And for that I have shared an image as well.**
Please help if anybody has achieved this. Thanks again for listening.

Comment: [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/)

Comment: @MD Thanks for the link, what I am trying to ask in the questions is, when we enter name of a place in the google maps, it draws a polygon on the map. To draw a polygon dynamically I will need co-ordinates (latitudes and longitudes). How is the website getting it? Is there any API for this? Thanks again for the response.

Comment: @MD I got this from the link that you shared https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes. But, I need Latitudes and Longitudes to draw it. Do I need to manually add co-ordinates like as done in the link above or there is a way to get co-ordinates dynamically from some Google API. I am not aware of the facts here, sorry for asking anything wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you need the polygon of the place you are asking. Unfortunately geocoding (and reverse geocoding) which is the feature you are using when "write the name and search" works only for points (single coordinates) in the google API. You should find a web service which gives you the polygon of the places. I'm not aware of world wide service, you can try with openstreetmap if it fits your needs

Comment: @NDorigatti "You need the polygon of the place your are asking". Yes, thats absolutely what I am trying to achieve. "You should find a web service which gives you the Polygon of the places" Yes, this is what I am lacking here. You understood what I want, thanks for making my question clear.

Comment: As and advice/help, i can tell you that online there are places for retrieving polygons for specific cities. These are called WFS and are publicly available sometime. It is not that easy in your case (because you want to search) but can help. Do you want it world wide or is it restricted to some places? 
For your convenience, i found Geocoding gives you the bounding box of the area, you will not highlight correctly but you can at least zoom to the correct extent (boundary)

Comment: @NDorigatti Yes, I need it for a specific place. "Geocoding gives you the bounding box of the area", Can you please put some light on this? Thanks for being so helpful :)

Comment: If you go: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714245,-74.005838&sensor=false
you can explore the resulting JSON;
for each result, ignore address_components and move to geometry:
it contains location (usually the center) and viewport, which are the coordinates you can use to build a boundary for zooming on the place. It is just a rectangle but is more than nothing, right?

Comment: Thanks @NDorigatti I will try it and let you know about it. I was actually thinking of checking what Google Maps (Website) returns when a name of the place is entered. I will surely try this (which might take some time) and let you know for any results. Thanks for helping, really thankful. Thanks again.

Comment: @class Android Have you get anything useful? I also need this solution.

Comment: @KhanSquare I didn't find anything relevant at that time, I had to add Lat/Longs manually for that Area. I got them from Google Maps (manually). If you find something, please add to the comments, Thanks.

Comment: :D :D :D  Same here... I also doing this nonsense.

Comment: @KhanSquare I don't know why they don't have an API for this when they have it for website. A little annoying.

Comment: Have you tried something with KML?
Visit the link (Import KML onto your map) ... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/#geojson
Note that it is a mobile screen. It means this all is happening on mobile side.